# log4j2.xml is overriden. How to stop it?

Tags: tomcat, logging, log4j, log4j2

I have a Tomcat server and in the Tomcat server, there are three projects, each having a log4j2.xml configuration file. The tomcat has its own log4j2.xml file as well. When the projects are started, the log4j2.xml file of the tomcat is taken and the others are ignored (or overriden).

The version of the Tomcat server is 7.0.67 and the version of the log4j is 2.5.

[image]

How can I achieve that all log4j2.xml files are considered?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found my answer to my own question.

That required two steps,

1. Adding log4j-web jar to my classpath.
2. I configure the web.xml file of the web applications in the Tomcat server.

For more detailed solution, [click here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html)